# Call to undefined function iconv() fatal error - Suitecrm

Tags: fatal-error, sugarcrm, suitecrm

Using suitecrm 7.9.1

I am facing the below error whenever i try to create a lead , that is after submitting the create lead form.

Facing the same error whenever i try to import a csv file . This error occurs only on live server

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function iconv() in
> /home/testsite/public_html/modules/AOD_Index/Lib/Zend/Search/Lucene/Field.php:222
> Stack trace: #0
> /home/testsite/public_html/modules/AOD_Index/Lib/Zend/Search/Lucene/Index/SegmentWriter/DocumentWriter.php(131):
> Zend_Search_Lucene_Field->getUtf8Value() #1
> /home/testsite/public_html/modules/AOD_Index/Lib/Zend/Search/Lucene/Index/Writer.php(244):
> Zend_Search_Lucene_Index_SegmentWriter_DocumentWriter->addDocument(Object(Zend_Search_Lucene_Document))
>
> ## 2 /home/testsite/public_html/modules/AOD_Index/Lib/Zend/Search/Lucene.php(1410):
>
> Zend_Search_Lucene_Index_Writer->addDocument(Object(Zend_Search_Lucene_Document)) #3 /home/testsite/public_html/modules/AOD_Index/AOD_Index.php(310): Zend_Search_Lucene->addDocument(Object(Zend_Search_Lucene_Document))
>
> ## 4 /home/testsite/public_html/modules/AOD_Index/AOD_LogicHooks.php(36):
>
> AOD_Index->index('Leads', 'b81874eb-1233-5...') #5
> /home/testsite/public_html/include/utils/LogicHook.php(262):
> AOD_LogicHooks->saveModuleChanges(Object(L in
> /home/testsite/public_html/modules/AOD_Index/Lib/Zend/Search/Lucene/Field.php
> on line 222

what is the cause for this error .
newbie to the suitecrm, how to fix it .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

iconv is a PHP extension. look for an entry in php.ini that you can uncomment, or see following link

https://www.hackersgarage.com/iconv-php-extension-installation-without-recompiling-php.html

Comment: Added iconv extension to cpanel , its working fine now .. Thank you so much ...!!

Answer (score 15):

Install the Iconv module on your CPanel.

1. Open WHM
2. EasyApache 4
3. Customize
4. PHP extensions
5. Find iconv. Enable the one matches your PHP version
6. Review
7. Provision